# Access localhost:9222/json directly from Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Is it possible to get the information presented in e.g. `http://localhost:9222/json` directly from Puppeteer without having to make the http request?

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember what information exactly  in `http://localhost:9222/json` but you can use `browser.version()` for learn browser version and you can learn `browser.wsEndpoint()` for browser endpoint url, without http request.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone know the answer to this? I have a similar question, my problem is that I want to know where the `page.goto(url)` resolves

I have a code like this:

```
url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/"
response = await page.goto(url, 
            waitUntil=['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'], timeout=30000
        )
```

Then I want to check when the `url` redirect, so I did it something like this

```
url_resolve = response.url
```

But the problem is I'm still getting the original `url` I requested, but checking `http://localhost:9222/json`, I'm getting something like this

```
[{
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/BA2493F44C89E9255BD0FE6B060AB0FE",
   "id": "BA2493F44C89E9255BD0FE6B060AB0FE",
   "title: "Some Website - Design",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "http://www.somewebsite.com/home/13112321/main.html"
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/BA2493F44C89E9255BD0FE6B060AB0FE"
}]
```

So what I really want is to get the `url` I'm getting from the endpoint `http://localhost:9222/json`, which only accessable via http request not from puppeteer itself, btw I'm using `pyppeteer`

**Update:**

So I found a way to go around solving my use case, What I did was to use the `evaluate` method, by simply adding

```
current_url = await.page.evaluate('window.location.href', force_expr=True)
```

Then I'll get the current url of the open tab

Got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460518/getting-the-url-of-a-new-tab-in-pyppeteer)